# What is the difference between google.cloud.pubsub_v1 and google.pubsub_v1?

Tags: python, google-cloud-pubsub

I have noticed that there is code to create publishers and subscribers in two paths, `google.cloud.pubsub_v1` and `google.pubsub_v1`. They both have similar functionalities, but `google.pubsub_v1` seems to have a higher level interface. What is the difference

Answer (score 0):

After exploring the official repo and the history of it, it seems like the two codebases have different origin, having `google.pubsub_v1` being the last to be generated using a new code generator google has created a [Pubsub PR on microgenerator](https://github.com/googleapis/python-pubsub/pull/158) for its libraries.

If you are looking on choosing one of the APIs **without asyncio, choose `google.cloud.pubsub_v1`**, as it has better features such as cooked-in retry schemes for publishing

Behind the scenes, `google.cloud.pubsub_v1` uses the synchronous client of `google.pubsub_v1`.